# incorrect output while calling function

Tags: python, function, output

I'm a noobie, learning to code and i stumbled upon an incorrect output while practicing a code in python, please help me with this. I tried my best to find the problem in the code but i could not find it.

Code:

```
def compare(x,y):
    if x>y:
        return 1
    elif x==y:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1

i=raw_input("enter x\n")
j=raw_input("enter y\n")

print compare(i,j)
```

Output:

```
-> python python.py
enter x
10
enter y
5
-1
```

The output that i had to receive is 1 but the output that i receive is -1. Please help me with the unseen error in my code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string always.

so you have to convert the input values into numbers.

```
i=raw_input("enter x\n")
j=raw_input("enter y\n")
print compare(i,j)
```

should be

```
i=int(raw_input("enter x\n"))
j=int(raw_input("enter y\n"))
print compare(i,j)
```

Comment: now i understand that raw_input returns string value if my code is as follows: `def compare(x,y):
    if x>y:
        return 1
    elif y>x:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

i=raw_input("enter x\n")
j=raw_input("enter y\n")

print compare(i,j)` then the output that i recieve is: `-> python python.py
enter x
10
enter y
5
-1` how come the output is -1 rather than 0

Comment: you can compare alphabets also, they are ordered as per their ascii value

you can check in the repl by typing `'b' < 'a'` which should give you False and `'a' < 'b'` will give you True.  That is why you were not getting 0

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `raw_input()` returns a string, not an integer.

Therefore, what your function is actually doing is checking "10" > "5", which is `False`, therefore it falls through your `if` block and reaches the `else` clause.

To fix this, you'll need to cast your input strings to integers by wrapping the values in `int()`.

i.e.

`i = int(raw_input("enter x\n"))`.

Comment: Actually there's nothing like "casting" in Python. "casting" (in "type casting") means "interpreting the same variable as being of another type", which is not possible in Python. What `int(somestr)` does is instanciating a new `int` object from the numeric value of `somestr`, so the correct term would be "converting", not "casting".

Answer (score 0):

Use the inbuilt cmp builtin function.

```
>>> help(cmp)
Help on built-in function cmp in module __builtin__:

cmp(...)
    cmp(x, y) -> integer

    Return negative if x<y, zero if x==y, positive if x>y.
```

So your function will look like this.

```
>>> def compare(x,y):
...   return  cmp(x,y)
...
>>>
```

Then get two variables using raw_input() which returns string, So If you are typing two numbers with a blankspace in the middle, splitting based on blank space will save two numbers in these x and y, and then apply map function which takes two parameters, one int function and the sequence which is nothing but a list created out of split().

```
>>> x,y = map(int, raw_input().split())
3 2
```

Now Comparing the x and y, Since x = 3 and y =2, Now since as per the documentation of cmp(), It Return negative if xy.

```
>>> compare(x,y)
1
>>> compare(y,x)
-1
>>> compare(x-1,y)
0
>>>
```

Comment: Don't post screen captures as answers please - and posting code without explanations does not make for a good answer.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers: Updated my answer with detail description.